# Solve $Ax=b$ if $A$ is singular

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&-0.25\\ -2&2&2.5\\ 2&-1&-1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-0.25\\ -1.5\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I am trying to solve this problem. How can I do so if A is singular? I tried running it in Python and it has issues.

```
from scipy.linalg import solve

A=np.array([[-1,0,-0.25], [-2,2,2.5], [2,-1,-1]])
b=np.array([[-0.25,-1.5,1]])
x = solve(A, b.T)
```

I get `LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.`

Comment: If $A$ is singular then there are infinitely many solutions or no solution to $Ax=b$

Comment: The system of equations in the question seems to have nothing to do with the python script.

Comment: Fixed. I had tried another singular matrix A that I knew had a solution (according to an example).

Comment: How would I go about finding it if has a solution? Or is there now way?

Comment: You row-reduce the matrix, augmented with the vector. If you get a row of zeros augmented with a nonzero number, there is no solution

Comment: Ok, pardon my confusion but an RREF with the augmented solution yields an answer for x1:x3. Why is it that we say Ax=b "as no solution"?

Comment: by using PseudoInverse of the matrix the solution is $$x1=0.3018...,$$ $$x2=-0.1886...,$$ $$x3=-0.2075...$$